# Getting only first value of multi value string in User Profile Property

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property

I defined a multi value string for user profile properties in the backend of my SharePoint 2010. I'm reading the content from the created property like this: 
`propertyValue = profile[propname].Value.ToString();`
unfortunately i'm getting only the first stored value of the multi value field.

profile in the code is of type UserProfile and has GetUserProfile(accountName) from the UserProfileManager in it

Any Ideas how to get all multi values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profile property is actually a `UserProfileValueCollection`.

e.g.

```
UserProfileValueCollection propertyCollection = profile[propname];
foreach(var prop in propertyCollection)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prop.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that UserProfilePropertyCollection exists? Doesn't work for me and i can't find anything on the internet about it..

Comment: On the top of my head it's UserProfileValueCollection in stead of UserProfileProperyCollection

Comment: Sorry, I was working off 2007... If you use 'var' it should work ok...

Comment: Just tested it - my code looks like this: ` if (profile[propname].Value != null)
                    {                       
                        UserProfileValueCollection propertyCollection = profile[propname];
                        propertyValue = propertyCollection.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        propertyValue = String.Empty;
                    }

                    sectionProperties.Add(propDisplayName, propertyValue);` still there ist just one Value inside of the propertyCollection

Comment: Edited per suggestion